# Paginate WordPress Category Pages

Tags: categories, query-posts, pagination, page-template

I am using the following `query` on my `category.php` template:

```
<?php
    $paged = (get_query_var("paged")) ? get_query_var("paged") : 1;
    query_posts("posts_per_page=2&paged=".$paged);
?>
```

The one thing that I've noticed is that this breaks my pagination...with this code the pagination returns "paged" in the url: http://example.com/?cat=12&paged=2, fortunately or unfortunately it's a simple issue with the url...instead of returning "paged" in the url, it should return "page" or http://example.com/?cat=12&page=2.

I have tried altering my code (as explained: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var for pages):

```
<?php
    $page = (get_query_var("page")) ? get_query_var("page") : 1;
    query_posts("posts_per_page=2&page=".$page);
?>
```

But that doesn't work either...any ideas?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`paged` is correct unless you're using pretty permalinks, however, if you're just trying to alter posts per page for categories, you should be using the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action, there's no reason to use `query_posts` in the template:

```
function wpa85791_category_posts_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 2 );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpa85791_category_posts_per_page' );
```

Comment: Milo, I am using `query_posts` simply to restrict the number of posts per page...how do I apply your fix to just my category.php template?

Comment: put that in your theme's `functions.php` file.